# Skip header row in Excel SSRS datasource

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using an excel spreadsheet as a datasource in an SSRS report.  The excel spreadsheet has a header row, which I would rather not have displayed in my results.  Is there a way to ignore that row in SSRS?

Comment: If you know it will always be there, you can just put an expression in the hidden property for the detail rows, and set hidden to true for the first row.

Comment: Are you using **HDR=YES** in your connection string properties?